# Finding specific morphisms for a category product

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

here's a question that's giving me headaches:

Given a category product $(P,\pi_1,\pi_2)$ of objects $A_1$ and $A_2$, I need to show that there exists applications $f_1$ and $f_2$ such that: 
$$\pi_i \circ f_j = \delta_{ij}\text{id}_{A_i} $$
$i,j\in \{1,2 \}$ and $\delta_{ij}=1$ if $i=j$ and $\delta_{ij}=0$ if $i \neq 0$. [Here's the diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvGAW.png])

I guessed  that defining  $f_1(A_1)=h(\phi^{-1}(A_1))$ would make the identity part for $\pi_1 \circ f_1$ work, but I have no idea for the $\pi_2 \circ f_1=0$.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Presumably you are working in the context of abelian categories (or something similar), otherwise your $\delta_{ij}$ doesn't make sense. Morphisms usually don't have inverses, so $\phi^{-1}$ may not exist.

Comment: Yes,  I missed that.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have morphisms (I assume that you actually have a way to make sense of the notation)

$$ 1 \mathrm{id}_{A_1} : A_1 \to A_1$$
$$ 0 \mathrm{id}_{A_1} : A_1 \to A_2$$

then you don't have to do any work at all. The *very definition of product* is that there is a unique function  $ A_1 \to A_1 \times A_2$ that satisfies the identities you require $f_1$ to satisfy.

Comment: In the way I understand this,  I see $ f_1$ as the inverse of $ \pi_1$ and vice  versa for $ f_2$. I assume I must be wrong because that doesn't garantee that $ f_2 \circ \pi_1$ is 0. Actually, I'm not even sure what 0 is...

Comment: @GaëtanMorin: $g \circ h = \mathrm{id}$ doesn't mean $g$ and $h$ are inverses: you need $h \circ g = \mathrm{id}$ too.

Comment: I finaly understood! It really comes from the definition.